# How do I write this linq inner query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I want to write a linq query where I want to check each iteration of an inner list. Without linq, this would basically be a nested for loop - like this:

```
List<Item> selectedList = new List<Item>();
            foreach (Item i in item.Children)
            {
                var childPages = ((from innerItem in i.Children
                                   where innerItem.Template.BaseTemplates.Contains(new TemplateItem(ContextDatabase.GetItem(templateID)), new Compare())
                                   select innerItem).DefaultIfEmpty());

                if (childPages.First() == null)
                {
                    selectedList.AddRange(childPages.ToList());
                }
            }
```

I converted the inner loop into a linq query - now I want to convert the for loop into the same - is there a way to write this in linq, so that I don't have to have the foeach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting an item from the database on each iteration in order to do a comparison ... is that what you absolutely require? There should be an easier way to do the comparisons based on just id's (but would need more information from you I think).

Anyway, to remove the outer `foreach`, you can do another `from` clause:

```
var childPages = (from i in item.Children
                 from innerItem in i.Children
                 where innerItem.Template.BaseTemplates.Contains(new TemplateItem(ContextDatabase.GetItem(templateID)), new Compare())
                 select innerItem).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

But again, I'd look closely at the need for `ContextDatabase.GetItem(templateID)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your classes, so this is a best guess. Also, I'm assuming you don't have to create a new instance of `TemplateItem` and `Compare` repeatedly inside the LINQ statement.

```
var templateItem = new TemplateItem(ContextDatabase.GetItem(templateID));
var comparer = new Compare();

selectedList.AddRange(item.Children.SelectMany(
    x => x.Children.Where(y => y.Template.BaseTemplates.Contains(templateItem, comparer))));
```

*(I'm using the method syntax here instead of query syntax, since that's what I'm more familiar with. The results should be the same.)*

Comment: noted about the new class instance every iteration - absolutely correct, don't need that (was just for the example). Sorry I can't mark both the answers - they both worked.